# A Conflicted Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

My infix will give you a name
My suffix will help you with pain

My prefix will make you frown
My whole will let you down

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> Disappointment

My infix will give you a name

> To appoint someone as leader means to name him or grant him the name "leader"

My suffix will help you with pain

> Ointment as in medicine

My prefix will make you frown

> Dissapointing someone will make them frown (or at least sad)

My whole will let you down

> Dissapointment will let you down, that's what it means

Comment: The prefix line isn't quite right, but other than that, you got it!

Comment: Somehow I misread your prefix clue as rot13(qvfnccbvagzrag vafgrnq bs qvfnccbvagvat). My original intent for the prefix line was rot13(qvf, nf trggvat qvffrq pna znxr lbh sebja), but yours also works, so have a check!

Comment: In slang rot13 qvffvat vf qvferfcrpgvat fb "qvf" pbhyq or qvferfcrpg gung znxrf lbh sebja